# How to use English as language but belgian (or other) keyboard layout during Ubuntu 12.04 server installation?

Tags: 12.04, keyboard-layout, language-support, system-installation

I can't set the Belgian keyboard layout during installation without setting the language to Dutch.

I really don't like to use Ubuntu server in any another language besides English, it's really confusing.

[image]

Comment: Ok  this got migrated but it specific to a server installation, not the consumer desktop version. That's why I thought it would be more appropriate on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

In a default setup, you will get asked separately about language and keyboard layout. You can set any combination – I frequently install Ubuntu Server in English but with a German keyboard layout.